# PostAsJsonAsyncResponse is not returning the result

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpclient

I'm having issues retrieving the response with the populated result within the Dispatch method, I'm not sure what I'm missing :(
The issue seems to be when it's deserializing as the responseBody is correct until that point.
Can anyone help?

```
 public async Task<Response> Dispatch(DispatchItem dispatchRequest)
        {
            var url = string.Format("dispatch/dispatchitem.json");
            
            var response = PostAsJsonAsyncResponse<DispatchItem , DispatchResponse>(url, dispatchRequest);
            response.Wait();

            return new Response();

        }
```

```
  protected async Task<Response<TResponse>> PostAsJsonAsyncResponse<TModel, TResponse>(string url, TModel model)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var authCredential = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{Username}:{Password}");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                    new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(authCredential));
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(APIUrl);

                var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, model);
                response.Wait();
                var responseBody = await response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                if (!response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    throw new ApiException(response.Result.StatusCode, responseBody);
                
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response<TResponse>>(responseBody);


            }
        }
```

```
 public class Response : Response<string>
    {
    }

    public class Response<T>
    {
        public T Result { get; set; }
        public bool IsSuccessful { get; set; }
     
    }
}
```

```
 public class DispatchResponse
    {
     
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public guid Reference { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: You're returning a new object of Response (which would be initialized, but empty). Why not await PostAsJsonAsyncResponse() and return the `response` variable?

Comment: Before it’s getting to returning the new response the response.result is null. It’s when it’s doing the Json deserialise where it’s not working

Comment: Do you want to clarify your question? Did you not get a response object (i.e. the code is stuck), or did you get an exception (what type of exception at where)? Just IMO, you shouldn't use `.Wait()` at all, try to `await` on all the async calls and see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: `response.Wait();` should be `await response` (or just inline it), otherwise you can deadlock

Comment: Code isn't stuck ,

Comment: Code isn't stuck , 
var responseBody = await response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); returns   {"Id":"1233444","Reference:"e758b8ff-2b19-4140-9591-7f2ec3ad46b3"}

However when it returns back into the Dispatch method, 
response object
{ID = 11,
Status = RantoCompletion,
Exception = Null,
CreationOptions =None, 
CancellationPending = false, 
AsyncState =null,
Result { isSuccessful = false, Result = null}
}

Basically I want it to have the Id & Reference in the Response.Result object when it returns

Comment: You might want to update your question with the JSON returned. It's a JSON serialization problem. Your JSON can't be deserialized into `Response<DispatchResponse>` as the structure isn't match.

Comment: @user1801525 Your second posted result in your comment looks for me like the Task is not finished properly. You should use `await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, model);` to ensure a correct task handling. I ran into a similar issue some months ago.